# Query for open tasks in Asana

Tags: asana

We're looking at using Asana to combine CRM, administration and issue tracking in a web dev firm.  The key feature we need is a view of the "next actions" or "top [1|2|3] priorities" across all projects in a workspace, irrespective of who they are assigned to.   It seems Asana does not provide this out of the box (is that right?) so I am looking into writing API queries to pull this out into a dashboard of our own.

I understand you don't want to let people pull ALL tasks in one workspace, as it may grow, but is there a way to pull out the top few open tasks in each project, without having to specify the assignee?

Answer (score 3):

(I work for Asana)

Currently, the API allows you to grab all tasks in a project, see https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects. It will return them in ranked order (the same as they would show up in the Asana UI), however it won't limit them to some number; you'll have to get them all. Limits and pagination are on our roadmap to enable developers to work more efficiently with larger projects and workspaces.

So, it seems like you'd want to grab all projects, then iterate through them and query all tasks - this will give you their name and ID by default. If you want more detail for the ones you're going to show, then I recommend querying the details on each of those tasks individually.